# how to pass down multidimensional pointers/arrays to recursive function

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to write a function that accepts an array of 'm' dimensions of 'n' elements each, and a pointer to other-trivial-function. The function will call itself at each dimension, iterates through its elements and call each time the function pointed to by the mentioned pointer (the trivial one).
The problem is that I couldn't find a way to define a function *general enough* as to accept an array of any dimensions, or a pointer to an array of any dimensions. Basically because every time the function calls itself it gets rid of one dimension, which is incompatible with the function prototype and definition.
I wrote a function that accepts a single-dimension pointer and threat it as multidimensional according to other two arguments, i.e. the total amount of elements, and the sizes of each dimension.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void goesThrough (int *, int *, size_t, void (*) (int));
    void print (int);

    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int (* ptrToArray) = array;

/*
 * Arguments are a pointer to an array, an array of sizes for each 
 * dimension, the amount of elements, and a pointer to whatever 
 * function.
 */
    goesThrough (ptrToArray, (int []) {2, 3}, 6, print);
    return 0;
}

void goesThrough (int * anArray, int * dimSize, size_t quantity,
                  void (* aFunction) (int))
{
    size_t index;

    for (index = 0; index < (* dimSize); ++index)
    {
        if (quantity / (* dimSize) > 1)
        {
            goesThrough (anArray + (index * (quantity /(*dimSize))),
                         dimSize + 1, quantity / (* dimSize), aFunction);
        }
        else
        {
            aFunction (anArray[index]);
        }
    }
}

void print (int aValue)
{
    printf ("%d ", aValue);
}
```

However, I find two drawback with this approach. It feels like the 
compiler won't help if something goes wrong; and to read/write to a single member in these ***arrays*** I'd need to write my own functions too.

**Question1**: How to write this using multidimensional **arrays**?

**Question2**: Is recursion a better approach than loops in this case? if not, I'd appreciate an example using loops, (I would it anyway) ;). For better I mean any reason a serious programmer would choose it.

**EDIT**: I initially asked for ***arrays/pointers*** (**Q1**), but I meant ***arrays/pointers-to-arrays***

**NOTE:** Please notice that the matter here is to pass arrays of a number of dimensions that is different to the number of dimensions the function is expecting. To this regard edits or suggestions to the title are very much welcome.

Comment: `void goesThrough(void *p, ...)` will accept any object pointer for `p`.

Comment: @chux - Yes, but it'd be like building a house by making up the bricks. I don't want to write my own implementation of multidimensional arrays, I'd rather use the one that already exists. As I said above, accessing a single member of these arrays would require a new function.

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriel, this looks like an interesting question, yet I only came up with a partial answer and made this wiki.  The *** may still need work.  Good luck.

Recall that a dimension could be 1, so `quantity / (* dimSize) > 1` is not sufficient a test.

This uses a `level`: index into `dimSize` rather than `quantity`.

```
void goesThrough(void * anArray, size_t * dimSize, size_t level, void (*aFunction)(int)) {
  if (level > 1) {
    for (size_t index = 0; index < *dimSize; index++) {
      void *(*a)[*dimSize];  // ***
      a = anArray;
      goesThrough(a[index], dimSize + 1, level - 1, aFunction);
    }
  } else if (level > 0) {
    int *a = anArray;
    for (size_t index = 0; index < *dimSize;index++) {
      aFunction(a[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In my function, `* dimSize` is always a factor of quantity. This would mean that in the last call to `goesThrough`,  `quantity / (*dimSize) == 1`, which actually identifies both, the amount of dimensions the array has at this stage, and the factor `index` should be multiplied by with each iteration. Basically, whenever `quantity / (*dimSize) > 1` is `false`, `quantity / (*dimSize) ==` 1 is `true`. I'm still taking a look at your code, thanks for your answers!

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit confused about your code. Is `void *(*a)[*dimSize]` a pointer-to a pointer-to an array? what do you need it for? (and should it be declared after 'a'?). In the 'true' part of your if, when calling `goesThrough`, `a[index]` is the value of the array in the index position. Did you mean this?. Again, thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel  `void *(*a)[*dimSize]` is a [pointer to array (*dimSize) of pointer to void](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+*%28*a%29%5B42%5D).  I use `a`, assigned with `anArray`, to simplify the offset calculation of `goesThrough(a[index]...`, but I this is the part I am not confident about.  Will have to ponder it more when  I have time.

Answer (score 0):

In C99 and higher you may use variable length arrays to pass multidimensional arrays:

```
void foo(int n, int m, int a[n][m]);
```

or using pointer to array:

```
void bar(int n, int m, int (*a)[n][m]);
```

as pointer may be dereferenced to first row/column you may even pass it like this:

```
void bar2(int n, int m, int (*a)[m]);
```

and still accsess it like `a[i][j]`.

Please, note that `n` and `m` are declared in function declaration before the array itself.

Also, you would need to create a new array on each recursion call and copy the data to it:

```
void bar(int n, int m, int a[n][m]) {
    if ((n > 1) && (m > 1)) {
        int b[n-1][m-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m-1; j++) {
                b[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is because changing the `m` requires change of size of each row in memory.
Also naive approach of automatic allocation of array pushes it on stack. So you may want to do dynamic allocation:

```
int (*b)[m] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n) * (m));
```

To use or not to use recursion is tough question. When using recursion make sure that height of the recursion is limited. If it is tail recursion compiler may serialize it (but this is not guaranteed). If you have multiple recursion calls (as pass a quarter of array to a new recursion call like in quadtree) this may require some custom stack/queue to be implemented.

Comment: I'm afraid this's not why I asked. If I understand, (and I might not, no joke), you make a 2D loop to go through a 2D array. What I need is the function to be recursive, because if I had a 25D array I wouldn't like to write 25 times the same `for`, and should it also be general enough to take an array of any dimensions, not a fixed number of them. The size of each dimension is not a concern, as I'd very well use a loop for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> a single-dimension pointer and threat it as multidimensional

That is totally fine, because this is basically what c does.
The array_1 and array_2 are layed out the same in memory, it is just a matter of interpretation:

```
int array_1[60] = {
    111, 112, 113, 114, 115,
    121, 122, 123, 124, 125,
    131, 132, 133, 134, 135,
    141, 142, 143, 144, 145,

    211, 212, 213, 214, 215,
    221, 222, 223, 224, 225,
    231, 232, 233, 234, 235,
    241, 242, 243, 244, 245,

    311, 312, 313, 314, 315,
    321, 322, 323, 324, 325,
    331, 332, 333, 334, 335,
    341, 342, 343, 344, 345
};

int array_2[3][4][5] = {
    {{111, 112, 113, 114, 115},
     {121, 122, 123, 124, 125},
     {131, 132, 133, 134, 135},
     {141, 142, 143, 144, 145}},

    {{211, 212, 213, 214, 215},
     {221, 222, 223, 224, 225},
     {231, 232, 233, 234, 235},
     {241, 242, 243, 244, 245}},

    {{311, 312, 313, 314, 315},
     {321, 322, 323, 324, 325},
     {331, 332, 333, 334, 335},
     {341, 342, 343, 344, 345}}
};
```

But in the latter case you always need to know the sizes and dimensions at compiletime.

### Q1:

Thus said, your code works fine, although i recommend to declare something like `int subQuantity = quantity / *dimSize;` and use `subQuantity` for readability.

### Q2:

Right know you just apply the funcion to every element, this could be done much easier:

```
void for_each_how_you_would_probably_do_it(int *arr, size_t elementCnt, void (*fn)(int)){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < elementCnt; ++i){
        fn(arr[i]);
    }
}

void for_each_beacause_its_c(int *arr, size_t elementCnt, void (*fn)(int)){
    while(elementCnt--){
        fn(*arr++);
    }
}
```

In my opinion you should try writing iterative algorithms, recursive ones are hard to understand. In addition, i do not know if the compiler can perform tail recursion elimination.

---

> every time the function calls itself it gets rid of one dimension, which is incompatible with the function prototype and definition

That is what recursion is about, reducing the problem untill it gets trivial.

> Reducing

in this case means applying itself to the lesser dimension.

> Trivial

means, just one dimension is left.

---

> and to read/write to a single member in these arrays I'd need to write my own functions too

You can get the corresponding pointer with following code:

```
/* 
 * arr is the array
 * idx is an array of indice for each dimension (0-based like everything in c)
 * dimSisez are the sizes of each dimension
 * dim is the dimension
 */
int *get_p(int *arr, int *idx, int *dimSizes, int dim){
    int pos = idx[0];
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < dim; ++i){
        pos *= dimSizes[i];
        pos += idx[i];
    }
    return arr + pos;   /* &arr[pos] */
}
```

It is the same as using `&arr[idx[0]][idx[1]]...[idx[dim - 1]]` but again, when using multidimensional syntax in c you need to know the sizes at compile time.
By the way dimSizes[0] is never used, that is the reason you can omit the first size when givin multidimensional-arrays as parameter to functions.

---

One last thing:
You declared all your variables at the beginning of a block, like in the ansi-standard, but `(int []) {2, 3}` as parameter-value is not allowed in ansi.

Comment: The reason why I didn't use ++/-- on vars or indexes (as in your **Q2**) is that it won't work when going through the same dimension more than once. e.g. in `ar[2][3]` you'll call `f` once using the `++` op, then reading `ar[0]` and returning to the caller, then iterate to read `ar[1]` and call again, but by that moment your index/var is already incremented/decremented due to the former call, (unless decremented/incremented the opposite when the function exits). That's why I didn't use them.

Comment: As for ANSI: I don't understand much about standards but I can assure you that I'm not getting any complain about the literals `(int []) {2, 3}` using `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -o "%e" "%f"`. I only use them to test the function, by the way.

Comment: Now **Q1**: Lets say I don't want to write my own implementation of _recursion-compatible multidimensional arrays_ (as I already did), **Is there a way to define a recursive function that passes arrays of any number of dimensions, by using multidimensional arrays as defined in the standard?**

Comment: Now **Q2**: I know recursion is usually not even considered compared to loops, but that is my point. What is asked for in **Q2**, among others that you've already answered, is **a way to do this using loops**, whether it exists. I still have to take a look into your `* get_p`. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Some quibbles-- 1) recursive algorithms should be _easy_ to understand, that is the whole point; but, C does _not_ guarantee tail call optimization (though some compilers may do this). 2) "when using multidimensional syntax in c you need to know the sizes at compile time": C has had VLAs since C99 (optional in C11), for which array sizes are determined at runtime....

Comment: 3) "The `array_1` and `array_2` are layed out the same in memory, it is just a matter of interpretation." This can get you in trouble. True that they share the same memory layout, but note that it is undefined behavior to index into a 2d array as a 1d array. For example, `int arr[10][10] = { { 0 } };  int *ptr = &arr[0][0]; for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) { ptr[i] = 1; }` leads to undefined behavior, even though there is no attempted access outside of the 2d array. Even `ptr[10] = 1` is undefined behavior, because the access is oob the first row of `arr`.